# Why are arrays only allowed in certain places?

Tags: c#, arrays

As I understand it, C# has a syntax for writing arrays as such: `{ 1, 2, 3 }`.  Why is this invalid:

```
 x = { 1, 2, 3 }.GetLength(0);
```

while this is valid?

```
 int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
 x = numbers.GetLength(0);
```

Isn't the datatype of the expression `{ 1, 2, 3 }` the same as `numbers`?

Comment: You'll probably get a good answer, but you might find this useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax you refer to is an <strike>object</strike> collection initializer. It is useful when initializing an instance of different types. It does not, in itself, create an instance of a given type.

For instance, you can use it to declare arrays:

```
int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Lists:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> pairs = { { "One", 1 }, { "Two", 2 }, { "Three", 3 } };
```

You can still inline things to achieve your initial intention with a little more code:

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.GetLength(0);
```

Comment: No, that's not an object initializer. It's an array initializer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Isn't it technically a collection initializer?

Comment: No, not on its own - or rather, not in the context specified by the OP. I've added spec references to my answer. Collection initializers are part of object initializer expressions - this is simply an array initializer. (Bear in mind that collection initializers have been valid since C# 1, whereas object initializers and collection initializers were only added in C# 3.)

Comment: Whoops, I meant "Bear in mind that array initializers [...]" of course :)

Answer (score 9):

Arrays are allowed anywhere - but you can only use that particular syntax (which is called an *array initializer* for creating them as part of a variable declaration - or as part of a larger expression called an *array creation expression*.

You can still create them though:

```
x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.GetLength(0);
```

So within that, `new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }` is the array creation expression, and the `{ 1, 2, 3 }` part is the array initializer.

Array creation expressions are described in section 7.6.10.4 of the C# 5 spec, and array initializers are described in section 12.6.

Answer (score 2):

`x = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.GetLength(0);` will get you what you want since `{1, 2, 3}` isn't on its own an array, but rather an array initializer. And `GetLength()` works with the former but not the latter.